# Get selected Row in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Listener on the DoubleClick event in a ListView. I have also activated FullRowSelect.

So when I double-click a row, only the value in the  first column appears. I also tried it directly with `SelectedItems`.

Please help

Code:

```
private void lvRecipesPos_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String s = "";

    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvRecipesPos.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)
        {
            s += item.Text.ToString();
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The `ListView` has a `SelectedItems` collection, so you don't have to iterate all items and check if they're selected.

2) `Item` has a `SubItems` collection which holds the texts for all sub items

Comment: @Buddhi: It does, since .NET 1.1 accoording to MSDN. There's also a SelectedIndices property.